# How does one make their cat buff?

Tags: cats

I am no cat owner but I was seeing this video on Youtube about a really buff cat whose name is, of course, buff cat. Here is a picture:

[image]

My question is, how did this cat achieve this physique? Can the average cat achieve this physique or is it possible only for some breeds?

Comment: It's entirely possible that the video is fake. If the cat really was like that, it would have a significant toll on the cat's health.

Comment: I assume it’s a genetic defect/disease.

Comment: Whybwould it have negative consequences @JacobB

Comment: If animals develop (or are born with) abnormalities as extreme as what's shown, it usually causes other health issues. In this case, the weight of the cat would probably cause increased stress on its skeletal system, or perhaps some of its organs wouldn't be sufficient to deal with the increased size.

Comment: the picture show a cat that is overweight,overweight in cats are a big problem and it will lead to medical problems like diabetes https://catfriendly.com/feline-diseases/diabetes/ a overweight cat will have the same problems as overweight people do http://www.vetstreet.com/our-pet-experts/9-ways-being-overweight-can-hurt-your-cat

Comment: In humans overweight means a lot of fat, so you're telling this cat doesn't have muscle but is rather just fat? @trondhansen

Comment: That cat is definitely either overweight or otherwise unwell. Cats are ambush predators who are not at the top of the food chain; they need to be able to move quickly and fit into small spaces, two things this cat cannot do. A cat will not naturally achieve an unnatural body shape.

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom do not attempt to make a cat "buff". Such a thing will harm your cat, and if officials find you did it on purpose, they might charge you with animal abuse.

Answer (score 2):

I want to give you an answer to how a "buff"cat realy look,this is the cat i had from 1979 to 6/7-1997.[image]

He scared the shit out of other cats,yes the other cats did realy s--t themselves,i had to give my cat a bath when this did happen

Comment: And how did your cat achieve this physique

Comment: i am sorry to say he was an expert squirrel hunter the only part he did not eat was the tail so he had a collection outside our door,and keeping other cats away did probably keep him in shape,my friends told me that he was crazy but he was neutered so i do not know why he was so territorial.

Comment: Damn you had a Chad cat.